# Wordpress Avada Theme Option

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Unable to view my Avada's theme option.
After I clicked to theme option. It will display only some dot. And I cannot edit my menu as well.
I had disable those plugins & applied all the patches from Avada. But still didn't work for me.

Comment: Please raised this issue to the Avada support forum with your Valid Purchase code.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Wordpress are you using? If its 4.8 or above the easiest way is to downgrade your wordpress version.

For me Wordpress 4.7.5 works perfectly with Avada 5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

sometimes this kind of problems are caused by browser extensions, not by wordpress or the theme itself

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by updating to the newest Avada version.(Version 5.4.2)